# Why some methods of ObservableCollection and List might be unavailable?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I work on Windows Phone 8 app. Some methods of ObservableCollection and List are unavailable at several pages (not at all pages). Such methods as OrderBy and ElementAt. So, I can't sort my items in these collections because of it. How to find the reason of it? I have no idea.

Comment: Tools such as Resharper would suggest you are missing the using statement. This question shows some free alternatives to resharper you could try as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834439/what-are-some-alternatives-to-resharper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those aren't methods on `ObservableCollection` or `List` themselves. They're [*extension methods*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx) provided by the [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) class.

You probably just need an added `using` directive in your source code to make them available:

```
using System.Linq;
```

If that triggers another error saying that the namespace `System.Linq` isn't found, you'll need to add a reference to the `System.Core` assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Because those are not `List<T>` methods, they're extension methods defined in the [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) class. To use them, add `using System.Linq`.