# Alternative for checkstyle

Tags: c#, .net, convention

I am searching for an open source C#/.NET alternative for code convention, like Checkstyle (Eclipse/Java).

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/

It should be possible to create, remove and modify the conventions.

Comment: Check out ReSharper or StyleCop

Comment: ReSharper is great, but it is many many things. It is also not open source.

Comment: Did you check these alternatives to resharper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834439/what-are-some-alternatives-to-resharper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing I know of is Stylecop

- https://stylecop.codeplex.com
- https://github.com/StyleCop

You might also like to check out FxCop:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476

Comment: I have used StyleCop for many different setups of conventions and rules. It's a good choice, if you are willing to put the time needed into defining those rules.