# Resharper alternatives for sharpdevelop?

Tags: c#

Are there any extensions like Resharper available for SharpDevelop?
Something that will automatically insert the namespaces upon detection of classes or things like that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some alternatives to ReSharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834439/what-are-some-alternatives-to-resharper)